# How to convert this lambda expression into method reference

Tags: java, java-8

How to convert this lambda expression into method reference. Here `rs` is a `ResultSet` and `rowNum` is `int`.

```
(rs, rowNum) -> getXYZ(rs,rowNum);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the method reference of `(rs, rowNum) -> getXYZ(rs, rowNum)` is in fact only `this::getXYZ` (assuming that method is in the same class and it is not `static`, otherwise it would be `YourClass::getXYZ`).

But maybe the following will help to build other `BiFunction`s:

```
BiFunction<ResultSet, Integer, WhateverGetXYZReturnedType> yourMethodReference() {
    return (rs, rowNum) -> getXYZ(rs,rowNum); // or just: this::getXYZ
}
```

and use it with:

```
...(this::yourMethodReference)
```